# Avoiding Branching - but need to maintain code for multiple countries

Tags: architecture, internationalization, branch, cvs

We support more that 4 countries of a same set of code base with some specific changes for each country. we are using CVS , we have HEAD and branches for each countries. once we fix something in any branch, eventually we merge it into HEAD.

We just want to get out of this model where we can avoid merging issues.

Is there any strategy or process or other ways to avoid merging, but maintain one code base for all countries.? ( we try to achieve this : Check out from HEAD and deploy it in some country , and the application should work for the country with out any code changes)

One complicated way is to have checks in the code where the country is "XY" then do this.

But is there any other way apart from this code change, if you can think of?

Comment: Use a VCS that does branching and merging better. *runs*

Comment: What exactly are the per-country changes? Can they all be stored in one branch and pulled in at either compile time or run time?

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML dictionary or resourceBundles to abstract the localized data:

- [Localizing Resource Bundles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ssfs/v9r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.local.doc%2Ft_LocalizingResourceBundles.html)
- [XSLT Reflection](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1313)
- [Internationalization with XSLT](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch08_06.htm)